# How to efficiently append same element n times to a non-empty list?

Tags: python, list, performance

In Python, it's known that the most efficient way to create a list with `n` repetitions of the same element (let's say the string `'s'`) is by using list multiplication, as shown below:

```py
lst = ['s'] * 1000
```

However, when the list is non-empty initially, what would be the most optimal method to append the same element `n` times?

Here are a couple of methods that come to mind:

Method1:

```py
lst = [1,2,3]

for _ in range(1000):
   lst.append('s')
```

Method2:

```py
lst = [1,2,3]

lst.extend(['s'] * 1000)

# or
# lst.extend(['s' for _ in range(1000)])
```

But it's worth noting that Method 2 does create a temporary long `list`, e.g. `['s' for _ in range(1000)]`.

Are there any alternative approaches that are more efficient, both in terms of time complexity and space usage? Or among the existing methods, which one is deemed the most efficient?

Comment: both of these have the *exact same time complexity*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose:

```
def addition(N):
    lst = [1, 2, 3]
    return lst+['s']*N
```

I profiled the approaches:

```
import itertools

from performance_measurement import run_performance_comparison


def method1(N):
    lst = [1, 2, 3]
    for _ in range(N):
        lst.append("s")
    return lst


def method2(N):
    lst = [1, 2, 3]
    lst.extend(["s"] * N)
    return lst


def generator_approach(N):
    #@user2390182
    lst = [1, 2, 3]
    lst.extend("s" for _ in range(N))
    return lst


def addition(N):
    lst = [1, 2, 3]
    return lst + ["s"] * N


def itertools_approach(N):
    #@juanpa.arrivillaga
    lst = [1, 2, 3]
    lst.extend(itertools.repeat("s", N))
    return lst


approaches = [method1, method2, generator_approach, addition, itertools_approach]
for approach in approaches[1:]:
    data = [100]
    assert approach(*data) == approaches[0](*data)
run_performance_comparison(
    approaches,
    [
        1_000,
        3_000,
        5_000,
        10_000,
        30_000,
        100_000,
        300_000,
        500_000,
        1_000_000,
    ],
    title="Performance Comparison",
    number_of_repetitions=10,
)
```

[image]

It seems to me  `['s']*N` is very performant, but `itertools` beats it.

Profiling code:

```
import timeit
from functools import partial

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from typing import List, Dict, Callable

from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def data_provider(data_size, setup=lambda N: N, teardown=lambda: None):
    data = setup(data_size)
    yield data
    teardown()


def run_performance_comparison(approaches: List[Callable],
                               data_size: List[int],
                               setup=lambda N: [N],
                               teardown=lambda: None,
                               number_of_repetitions=5, title='Performance Comparison', data_name='N'):
    approach_times: Dict[Callable, List[float]] = {approach: [] for approach in approaches}
    for N in data_size:
        with data_provider(N, setup, teardown) as data:
            for approach in approaches:
                function = partial(approach, *data)
                approach_time = min(timeit.Timer(function).repeat(repeat=number_of_repetitions, number=1))
                approach_times[approach].append(approach_time)

    for approach in approaches:
        plt.plot(data_size, approach_times[approach], label=approach.__name__)
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xscale('log')

    plt.xlabel(data_name)
    plt.ylabel('Execution Time (seconds)')
    plt.title(title)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: This gives a different result than either of the two examples that the OP shows.

Comment: Also, `lst` is `None` in the end

Comment: well, your proposal doesn't *actually do what the OP wants*, which is to modify the list in-place, and it suffers from the same problem as the OP's second solution, which is that it requires auxilliary space, but as I suspected, these approaches will be faster... but thanks for going to the trouble of actually profiling!

Comment: I learned today that `pd.Series.groupby.nunique()` is slower than `.apply(pd.unique).map(len)` so I don't trust any claims about performance without profiling anymore :)

Comment: Awesome! I learned a lot from your post.

Comment: @SebastianWozny definitely a good instinct, although, you learn to get a good feel for these things once you've answered a lot of questions like these.

Comment: Easy to say when your instinct is on point :D

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a list multiplication or comprehension for extending. It will create a spurious list object in memory. You can use `extend` with any iterable however, so:

```
lst.extend('s' for _ in range(1000))
```

is just fine. No need to turn the generator expression into a list before passing it to extend. Nothing wrong with your Method1 either.

Note: this is speaking purely from an algorithmic standpoint. Both the loop and generator approach (while requiring less extra space) have the downside of not being as C-optimized as a list multiplication/comprehension (after all, they are generic concepts and can be used for other things than creating lists), so I would not be surprised if they were slightly slower.

Comment: how is this better than the loop the OP already showed? I suspect the runtime will actually be *slower* than the OP's first solution, although, maybe not

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It saves the temporary long list `['s'] * 1000`

Comment: @maplemaple there first solution makes no temporary list

Comment: It is not, but it illustrates the fact that you can pass an iterable to `extend` which the OP appeared unaware of.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes. However there are explicit python for loop which is not quite efficient. I'm thinking whether there is a method like list comprehension which will move all the operation in underlying c code. That will be faster.

Comment: @maplemaple list comprehensions are just regular Python loops. What *does* actually move the loop into C is using `['s']*1000`

Comment: @maplemaple it is **exactly** as efficient, a python for loop and a list comprehension emit the same bytecode for the actual looping. There are a couple of other micro-opitmizations, the biggest being that it doesn't have to go through the trouble of resolving `list.append` on each iteration (and gets a bespoke bytecode instruction)

Answer (score 2):

I would say, the pythonic way would be:

```
import itertools

lst.extend(itertools.repeat("s", 1000))
```

Although, it's not really that much better than your first solution.

I still suspect your second solution will be the *fastest*.